# How to use optional named parameters and *mulit_vars in same function call?

Tags: python, python-2.x

Assume you have a function like that:

```
def example(var1=None,var2=None,var3=None,*multi_values):
    print (var1,var2,var3,*multi_values)
```

Can you get around calling all the optional parameters and just adding stuff to the last one?

Example:

```
>>> multi=range(3)
>>> example(???)
(None,"hi",None,(1,2,3))
```

I don't want to do this:

```
>>> multi=range(3)
>>> example(None,None,None,*multi) #bad -> this doesn't use the default values
```

Comment: People, please stop tagging everything as duplicate after you know the answer. It's not a duplicate, because **kwargs is the answer, not the question.

Comment: Just because you call your vararg parameter a different name doesn't make it a different question. There's nothing special about `*args` and *kwargs` as names. Just the python standard naming.

Comment: @Falmarri: Okay, again. I see it's hard to understand, if you are so much into it, that it doesn't make a difference for you. If everybody knows what `** params` are for, then you are right. But if I don't know it, it's a valid question with the answer `put a ** parameter in the end instead of writing the parameters in front of your * parameter`. I didn't ask `What does ** do?` because I didn't even know it helps to answer my question.

Comment: Just because you didn't know how to ask your question, or what the terms were, or what the syntax for varargs is doesn't mean it's not a duplicate question.

Comment: Let's say you ask "How to say 'house' in German?" Is it, from your point of view, the same question as "What does the German word 'haus' mean?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option is to change you prototype to take an iterable as `multi_values` argument, instead of accepting an arbitrary number of parameters:

```
def example(var1=None, var2=None, var3=None, multi_values=None):
    if multi_values is None:
        multi_values = []
    # whatever
```

Then you can call the function as

```
example(multi_values=multi)
```

Another option is to accept `var1` through `var3` only as keywords arguments:

```
def example(*multi_values, **kwargs):
    var1 = kwargs.pop("var1", None)
    var2 = kwargs.pop("var2", None)
    var3 = kwargs.pop("var3", None)
    if kwargs:
        raise TypeError("Unknown keyword arguments")
    # whatever
```

In Python 3.x, this is supported by adding `var1` through `var3` *after* the `*multi_values` argument:

```
def example(*multi_values, var1=None, var2=None, var3=None):
    # whatever
```

This does basically the same as the previous example, with the additional advantage of better introspection.

Answer (score 3):

No. You have to provide all the named values before *args values.

You could however, use **kwargs to take additional named parameters.

```
def example(var1=None,var2=None,var3=None,**kwargs):

example(var4="something")
```